# autoit - randomize text replacement with stringreplace function

Tags: autoit

So I am in need of replacing string text with autoit using `stringreplace` but I need to randomize the output.

An example of what I need is

```
Stringreplace($string, "and", {also|as well})
```

My ultimate goal is to randomly replace the text with the following options based on the word "and" with also or as well

Comment: So for example, you'd want "The cat and the dog and the rat" to be transformed to "The cat also the dog as well the rat" or similar? Good question from a programming point of view, english is unlikely to be correct in the output though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this a long time ago.

It will convert this

```
My name is {John|Peter|Mark}! {Regards|Cheers|Get lost}!
```

to something like this

```
My name is John! Cheers!
```

It works with line breaks also.

```
Func SpintaxToTXT($TextWithSpintax)


    Dim $MSGMSG
    Dim $lines

    $lines = StringSplit($TextWithSpintax, @LF)


    For $z = 1 To $lines[0]

        If $z > 1 Then $MSGMSG &= @LF


        $d = StringSplit($lines[$z], "{}")

        For $i = 1 To $d[0]

            $MSGSplit = StringSplit($d[$i], "|")
            If @error Then
                $MSGMSG &= $MSGSplit[1]
                ContinueLoop
            EndIf
            $MSGMSG &= $MSGSplit[Random(1, $MSGSplit[0], 1)]

        Next



    Next


    Return $MSGMSG

EndFunc   ;==>SpintaxToTXT
```

Comment: | can't be used outside of {}. To fix this implement _StringBetween

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Global $options_A = StringSplit('also,as well,bla,blubb,that,this', ',', 2)

For $i = 0 To 20
    ConsoleWrite($options_A[Random(0, UBound($options_A) - 1, 1)] & @CRLF)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I made earlier. Works exactly the same as `StringReplace` except instead of taking a replacement string, it takes a function that returns the replacement string. The using Xenobiologist's array method, you get the desired result.

```
Local $sTest = "The cat and the dog and the rat."

ConsoleWrite(_StringReplaceCallback($sTest, "and", _MyCallback) & @LF)

Func _MyCallback($s)
    Local Static $aOptions = StringSplit("also|as well", "|")

    Return $aOptions[Random(1, $aOptions[0], 1)]
EndFunc   ;==>_MyCallback


Func _StringReplaceCallback($sString, $sFind, $funcReplace, $iOccurence = 0, $iCaseSense = 0)
    Local $sRet = ""
    Local $iDir = 1
    Local $iPos = 1

    If $iOccurence < 0 Then
        $iDir = -1
        $iPos = StringLen($sString)
    EndIf

    If $iOccurence = 0 Then $iOccurence = $iDir * StringLen($sString)

    While 1
        $i = StringInStr($sString, $sFind, $iCaseSense, $iDir, $iPos)

        If $iDir > 0 Then
            If Not $i Or Not $iOccurence Then
                $sRet &= StringMid($sString, $iPos)
                ExitLoop
            EndIf

            $sRet &= StringMid($sString, $iPos, $i - $iPos) & $funcReplace($sFind)
            $iPos = $i + StringLen($sFind)
        Else
            If Not $i Or Not $iOccurence Then
                $sRet = StringMid($sString, 1, $iPos) & $sRet
                ExitLoop
            EndIf

            $sRet = $funcReplace($sFind) & StringMid($sString, $i + StringLen($sFind), $iPos - $i - StringLen($sFind) + 1) & $sRet
            $iPos = $i - 1
        EndIf

        If $iOccurence <> 0 Then $iOccurence -= $iDir
    WEnd

    Return $sRet
EndFunc   ;==>_StringReplaceCallback
```

It's probably worth noting that there is actually a simpler solution for this, provided the replacement strings don't ever include "and" (or else you'll have an infinite loop), that just replaces one instance at a time:

```
Local $sString = "The cat and the dog and the rat."
Local $aOptions = StringSplit("also|as well", "|")

Do
    $sString = StringReplace($sString, "and", $aOptions[Random(1, $aOptions[0], 1)], 1)
Until Not @extended

ConsoleWrite($sString & @LF)
```

Comment: both examples just returned the number 84

Comment: @CesarBielich, What? They both work fine, and returning `84` wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: That's what I thought, but they did.